# Шифрование WebSocket через NGINX

Tags: nginx, websocket

Как я понял NGINX может проксировать WebSocket:
https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/websocket.html

Если мы поднимаем WS сервер(без SSL) и проксируем его таким образом через NGINX, то будет ли шифроваться WS трафик, если в NGINX настроен SSL сертификат?

Какая практическая разница между проксированием незашифрованного WS и WSS без проксирования?

Comment: не все прокси ещё умеют пропускать ws, они ещё про него не знают... wss - понять не могут -  пропускают. (грубо так объяснение)

Comment: @Вадим wss проксировать смысла нет, надо шифровать тем же сертификатом, что и сайт. А из ответа ранее я понял, что nginx как раз таки может не только проксировать но и шифровать ws. Правда пока ещё руки не дошли проверить

Comment: ты не понял, не все прокси могут пропускать ws, но все пропускают wss (старые прокси не понимают ws).

Comment: @Вадим ну меня по крайней мере интересует только nginx :)

Comment: не важно nginx или apache, если у тебя будет ws, то юзера за старыми проксями с тобой не смогут общаться.

Comment: @Вадим а причем тут клиенты? Или я чего то явно не знаю

Comment: а с кем у тебя связь через ws?

Comment: @Вадим с браузером и пк клиентом. Я думал это не имеет значения. Я выбрал ws(вместо обычных сокетов) чтобы не париться с сертификатами.

Comment: я повторюсь - старые прокси, которые могут стоять у некоторых твоих пользователей, могут не пропускать ws. Таких может быть не много, Как вариант - можно проверить без wss, а если будут проблемы - тогда уже и переходить на wss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
клиент --wss--> nginx --ws--> websocket-backend
```

По моему мнению это - оптимальная схема так как соединение с клиентом зашифровано nginx, который умеет делать это максимально эффективно, а бекенд занимается исключительно бизнес-логикой.

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется. `зашифровано nginx, который умеет делать это максимально эффективно` - буду считать это ответом на первый, основной вопрос.